# Software Requirements Specification translation

Tags: srs

I got a quick question for my spanish-speaking folks.

You know, in this profession becomes very natural to start thinking in English for several reasons, best documentation and books are in English, programming languages are in English and community resources like SO are in English.

I'm writing a Software Requirements Specifications for a web app I'm about to start coding, but a question rose, what is the correct translation for Software Requirements Specification document?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documento de Especificación de Requerimientos

Comment: Thanks! I was fearing a bad textual translation.